# How expensive an operation is connecting to a Mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, memcached

In certain functions of the code, php will execute hundreds or in some cases thousands of queries on the same tables using a loop. Currently, it creates a new database connection for each query. How expensive is that operation? Would I see a significant speed increase by reusing the same connection? It could take quite a bit of refactoring to change this behavior and use the same database.

The php uses mysql_connect to connect to the database.

Just based on what I've said here, are there other obvious optimizations that you would recommend (I've read about locking tables for example...)?

EDIT:
My question is more about the benefit of using a single connection, not how to avoid using more than one.

Comment: What happenned when you tested it?

Comment: There is a good documentation at:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-costly-is-opening-and-closing-of-a-db-connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/mysql_connect) states:

> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned.

So, unless you're connecting with different credentials, changing that part of your code will not affect performance.

Comment: Unless he's calling `mysql_close()` after every query.

Comment: I hadn't realized that mysql_connect wasn't creating multiple connections. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use `Zend_Framework` and my database profiling shows that the connection itself takes nearly 10x longer than most of my queries.  I have two different databases that I connect to, and only connect once to each for each request.

I'd say reconnecting for every query is poor design, but the question of refactoring is more complex than that.  Questions that need to be asked:

1. Are there current performance problems?
2. Have you done code profiling to narrow down where the performance issues are occurring?
3. How much time will be required for this refactoring?  Take into account the testing involved, not just coding time.

Comment: There are current performance problems. I have not done code profiling. I don't know how much time refactoring would be, since I'm not 100% familiar with the code base.

Comment: Sound like this is a good candidate for refactoring! To reiterate though, code profiling should be a prominent factor in prioritizing refactoring.

Comment: I got a down-vote on this one. I would have been nice if the voter had left a comment as to why.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question should be obvious. If its not obvious to you then it should still be obvious how to find out for yourself how much impact it has.

> are there other obvious optimizations

No - because you've not provided any details of the table's structure nor the queries you are running.